# trouble loading .geodatabase file onto android app

Tags: android, arcgis

i am trying to import a .geodatabase file on android platform,but having trouble to do so.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio1:
        if (checked)
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: Roads",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try{

                    //Open the geodatabase file
                    Toast.makeText(this, "before geodatabase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Geodatabase geodatabase = new Geodatabase("/new_file_geodatabase.geodatabase");
                    //private GeodatabaseFeatureTable geodatabaseFeatureTable;
                    //get the geodatabase feature table
                    geodatabaseFeatureTable = geodatabase.getGdbFeatureTableByLayerId(0);
                    //create a feature layer
                    Toast.makeText(this, "before again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(geodatabaseFeatureTable);
                    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "after geo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   
        Toast.makeText(this, "Roads loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    case R.id.radio2:
        if (checked)
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've selected: Villages and Banks", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        local = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("file:///mnt/sdcard/vill n bnk.tpk");
        map.addLayer(local);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Villages and Banks Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

if you can see in the first radiobutton clicked option,inside try block i have put 3 toast messages to check the flow of program and have noticed that after displaying "BEFORE GEODATABASE" toast the flow control is going into catch block.I guess code following that toast message (inside try block is not working).

I am pretty sure everything with the xml file, android manifest file and other supporting files are good to go.

Can i Have any suggestions on whats wrong with the code.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could include `e.getMessage()` to the text of your "catch" toast and tell us what it says.

Comment: the error message reads,"Database file cannot be loaded".

Answer (score 0):

```
Geodatabase geodatabase = new Geodatabase("/new_file_geodatabase.geodatabase");
```

I doubt very much that you managed to put `new_file_geodatabase.geodatabase` in `/`, Android's root directory. If you did, I salute you. If not, you need to **use the absolute path to your .geodatabase file**.

Most likely, the [`Geodatabase(String)` constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/Geodatabase.html#Geodatabase(java.lang.String)) is throwing a `FileNotFoundException` as advertised.

If you want to verify that the file does not exist, try this as a test:

```
File f = new File("/new_file_geodatabase.geodatabase");
Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Does the file exist? " + f.exists());
```

Check the log. It will print "false," because `/new_file_geodatabase.geodatabase` does not exist. Your file might be in `/mnt/sdcard` or `/mnt/extSdCard` or somewhere else, but it is not in `/`.

Comment: Gary i have tried it with other sample geodatabase files and it works fine,but "new_file_geodatabase.goedatabase" is my generated geodatabase file.I doubt there must be something wrong with the geodatabse file.

Comment: How can i import a .gdb file into an Android Project?

Comment: You can't read a file geodatabase (.gdb) on Android. You need to use a Runtime geodatabase (.geodatabase).

Comment: I just revised my answer to add a test to verify that the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few combinations of code to get the task done...
Attached them below

1.Simple code without using the concept of network

This one reads an error : DATABASE FILE CAN'T BE OPENED

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeRoutingAndGeocoding();
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    local = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("file:///mnt/sdcard/SanDiego.tpk");
    map.addLayer(local);

    }

private void initializeRoutingAndGeocoding() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "in initialize and geo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //String networkPath = "/RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase";
                    //String networkName = "Streets_ND";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after files initied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Geodatabase geodatabase = new Geodatabase("file:///mnt/sdcard/RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase");
                        geodatabaseFeatureTable = geodatabase.getGdbFeatureTableByLayerId(0);
                        featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(geodatabaseFeatureTable);
                        map.addLayer(featureLayer);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        popToast("Error while initializing :" + e.getMessage(),true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

2.Using Network file works perfectly fine. NO ERRORS

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeRoutingAndGeocoding();
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    local = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("file:///mnt/sdcard/SanDiego.tpk");
    map.addLayer(local);

    }

private void initializeRoutingAndGeocoding() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "in initialize and geo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String networkPath = "/RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase";
                    String networkName = "Streets_ND";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after files initied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mRouteTask = RouteTask.createLocalRouteTask(extern
                                + networkPath, networkName);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        popToast("Error while initializing :" + e.getMessage(),true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

3.Just to get the message clearly conveyed to you.I have used the complete file address in this sample `file:///mnt/sdcard/RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase`
whereas in the previous one i didn't.

here the error says : UNABLE TO OPEN NETWORK

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeRoutingAndGeocoding();
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    local = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("file:///mnt/sdcard/SanDiego.tpk");
    map.addLayer(local);

    }

private void initializeRoutingAndGeocoding() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "in initialize and geo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String networkPath = "file:///mnt/sdcard/RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase";
                    String networkName = "Streets_ND";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after files initied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mRouteTask = RouteTask.createLocalRouteTask(extern
                                + networkPath, networkName);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        popToast("Error while initializing :" + e.getMessage(),true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

4.Having tried so many combinations i had a doubt that network name also count when dealing with geodatabase files. I changed the network name from `Streets_ND` to `abcd`and surprisingly the code doesn't work here.

The error reads : UNABLE TO OPEN NETWORK

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeRoutingAndGeocoding();
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    local = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("file:///mnt/sdcard/SanDiego.tpk");
    map.addLayer(local);

    }

private void initializeRoutingAndGeocoding() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "in initialize and geo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String networkPath = "/RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase";
                    String networkName = "abcd";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after files initied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mRouteTask = RouteTask.createLocalRouteTask(extern
                                + networkPath, networkName);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        popToast("Error while initializing :" + e.getMessage(),true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

5.Lastly, having experimented on sample data (downloaded from `https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/offline-routing/`) tried running my own data in the code.

The error reads : UNABLE TO OPEN NETWORK
But road.tpk file is displayed on the emulator.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeRoutingAndGeocoding();
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    local = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("file:///mnt/sdcard/road.tpk");
    map.addLayer(local);

    }

private void initializeRoutingAndGeocoding() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "in initialize and geo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String networkPath = "/new_file_geodatabase.geodatabase";
                    String networkName = "Streets_ND";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after files initied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mRouteTask = RouteTask.createLocalRouteTask(extern
                                + networkPath, networkName);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        popToast("Error while initializing :" + e.getMessage(),true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: For creating the Geodatabase object, don't use `file://`. Try this: `Geodatabase geodatabase = new Geodatabase("/mnt/sdcard/RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase");` That works if RuntimeSanDiego.geodatabase is in /mnt/sdcard.

Comment: This is the code i use but it doesn't work either:

//Open the geodatabase file
Geodatabase geodatabase = new Geodatabase("{/path/to/geodatabase}");

private GeodatabaseFeatureTable geodatabaseFeatureTable;

//get the geodatabase feature table
geodatabaseFeatureTable = geodatabase.getGeodatabaseFeatureTableByLayerId(0);

//create a feature layer
featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(geodatabaseFeatureTable);

mMapView.addLayer(featureLayer);

Comment: [Jeez people](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7398881), this is an edit to their question, not an answer.  Do you even look at these things in the review queue before clicking "Looks OK"?